# javascript path with Url.Content

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get standard path with javascript for images in my project
I used src for image as below

```
document.testImg.src = '../Images/test.png';
```

Do we have any option like below to make path consistent?

```
document.testImg.src = '@Url.Content(~/Images/test.png)';


<img name="testImg">
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this a .NET/C# project?

Comment: Sorry. Its a asp.Net MVC project with C#. But the context here is pure javascript which is included in project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably know you can't use Razor in Javascript unless that script is part of the Razor view. It's not the "sexiest" way but one way out is to have a "global" javascript URL variable in your Layout View/MasterPage.

for example in your shared layout you'll have a variable:

```
var AppUrl = '../Content/Images/';
```

so then in all your views you can use this consistent variable:

```
var myImageUrl = AppUrl + 'image.jpg';
```

p.s. Don't want to use variables ? Stick a function in your shared view instead:

For example in your shared layout you'll have a function:

```
function AppURL(url)
{
 return '../Content/Images/' + url;
}
```

so then in all your views you can use this:

```
var myImageUrl = AppUrl('image.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution for this. I used t4mvc for my project and updated all my magic strings. I thought this solution would be useful for few developers who have issues with paths.

Answer (score 0):

This way we can use `Url.Content()` few example code i added that may help others.

```
<p>This link goes to my `<a href="@Url.Content("~/")">`Application home page</a>.</p>

<p>Now let’s link to a view `<a href="@Url.Content("~/Controller/Action")">`in the Controller/Action directory</a>.

Url.Content("~/img/myImage.png")

<img src= "@Url.Content(Model.ImagePath)" alt="Sample Image" style="height:50px;width:100px;"/>
```